# Display the data in my html like the date

Tags: javascript, php, html, ionic-framework

I wanted to display the date of the system on my page so i created a php code and using my controller i use http.post. But my problem is this [image: This is the data that shows on my page]

This are my codes.
In my controller

```
var linkdate = 'http://127.0.0.1/mobile/date.php';

$http.post(linkdate).then(function(date) {
   $scope.response= date;
})
```

In my html

```
{{response}}
```

And in my php code

```
<?php
  $Today = date('y:m:d');
  $new = date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($Today));
  echo $new;
?>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? any help will do thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

```
$http.post(linkdate).then(function(data) {
    $scope.response= data.data;
})
```